# How to manage type-safety in POSIX shared memory

Tags: c++, posix, shared-memory

I have a 'program' that runs as multiple independent processes that use POSIX semaphores and shared memory to store and share common variables with each other. The problem is that so far this has been implemented as a main program which sets the initial values of the variables in shared memory, and the other programs rely on getting the address offset right to access a given variable.

I would like to improve on this design. An idea I had was to bundle together all methods for access to shared memory in a shared library, and have perhaps an enum as an argument to a GetVariable method, something like this

```
enum class SHMVariables: long 
{
  kVariable1 = address_offset_of_variable_1,
  kVariable2 = address_offset_of_variable_2,
  ... 
}

template <class T>
void GetVariable(SHMVariables var, T &) 
{ 
  // lock semaphore, do some memory boundary checks, and return the value of the variable
}
```

The challenge is that the variables may have different arithmetic types (some are user-defined structs with arithmetic type members) and I'm wondering what a best approach could be to manage type-safety. Could a map do the trick?

```
std::map<SHMVariables, std::size_t> // the value being assigned with something like sizeof(struct foo)
```

What are best practices when it comes to managing variables of different type in shared memory? Is shared memory even an appropriate choice?

Comment: Are the variables and types in shared memory fixed and known at compile time? If so, then why not just make a `struct` of them all that starts at the beginning of the shared memory?

Comment: The topic of sharing data through shared memory is quite nuanced. Your question is underspecified in whether readers need to wait for shared data updates or just need to get the latest version with no data races. In the former case, you need process shared mutex and condition variable (semaphore is inadequate), in the latter case you may only need a seqlock (semaphore is overkill). And it is a totally different story for shared memory queues. Read up [Boost.Interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) for full details and discussion.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica the variable types and default values are known at compile time, but the values can and probably will change during runtime.

Comment: @RodrigoTorres That's fine; a `struct` still works fine in that case.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin thank you for the suggestions. In most cases the readers only need to know the latest value of the variable, or the user defined struct. I was wondering if there was some way to code in type safety in the function that handles access to the shared memory. So instead of returning a pointer and leaving it  to the user to cast it to the right type, that I could return a pointer (or modify a reference) with the correct variable type that I know at compile time

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica ok, thanks! This might be a case then of me overly and needlessly complicating my life. Happens more often than I care to admit...